# Deleting rows via SQL query -- any way to speed up this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DELETE from Users 
Where Id in (
    SELECT TOP 200 u.id
    FROM users u JOIN
         playlists pl
         ON u.id = pl.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN
         playlistitems pli
         ON pli.PlaylistId = pl.id
    GROUP BY u.id
    HAVING count(pl.id) = 1 AND
           count(pli.id) = 0
)
```

Are there any pitfalls in this SQL query which would cause it to run really slowly? It takes me 1m32s to delete 200 rows, but there's 260,000 that I need to clean up..

Comment: probably it will run a lot faster without top 200,relative to the number of deleted rows per unit of time.Also query plan.

Comment: Could I please see an example of WHERE EXISTS?

Comment: The comments of that thread say, "This used to be true but in current versions (at least 2008) the optimizer is much smarter... it actually treats IN () just like an EXISTS ()."

Comment: Or maybe put your query in a BEGIN END block checking for rowcount in the same time.http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b5225ca7-f16a-4b80-b64f-3576c6aa4d1f/how-to-quickly-delete-millions-of-rows?forum=transactsql

Comment: You don't have 'order by' clause, so this query delete some random 200 records

Comment: And your RDBMS is ...?

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is pointless to join from `users` why don't you do this instead:

```
DELETE from Users 
Where Id in (
    SELECT TOP 200 pl.UserId
    FROM playlists pl
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         playlistitems pli
         ON pli.PlaylistId = pl.id
    GROUP BY pl.UserId
    HAVING count(pl.id) = 1 AND
           count(pli.id) = 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Index each of the tables on the ID column. Preferably a clustered index, but not essential.

given that you already have indexes, try something like this:

```
;with cte as 
(
    select 
        u.id,
        rank() over (partition by u.id) as rk
    from users u
    join playlists pl on pl.UserId = u.ID
    join playlistites pli on pli.PlaylistID = pl.ID
)
delete from cte
where rk > 200
```

Comment: They all have clustered indexes on the ID columns. I also rebuilt all indexes before executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- insert users to delete in #temp table
SELECT u.id
INTO #toDelete
FROM users u JOIN
     playlists pl
     ON u.id = pl.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN
     playlistitems pli
     ON pli.PlaylistId = pl.id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING count(pl.id) = 1 AND
       count(pli.id) = 0


-- increment or decrement at will
set @rowcount 200
select 'dummy' -- force @@rowcount > 0
while @@rowcount > 0
begin

   delete 
   from Users 
   where exists (select * from #toDelete td where td.id = users.id)

end
set @rowcount 0
```